# Summon custom arrow in 1.11.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How to summon an arrow that will fly in the east direction ,have a custom name "bomb" , and never stop flying.

I have tried by myself but i got a few problem:

The arrow that I summoned had particle trails and is not a normal arrow because it has potion effect's.

It will also only fly for a while not infinitely .

Comment: What exactly have you tried it? Can you post the command?

Comment: /summon arrow ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:bomb} and i found a thread for the arrow. For what i've read its impossible with hundreds of commands blocks at least to get it perfect

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248423/how-to-make-straight-flying-arrows-in-vanilla-minecraft

Answer (score 2):

The potion effect particles you are experiencing are due to [[MC-111533]](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-111533). You may have to wait until Mojang fixes this bug.

---

Normally making an arrow fly forever would require raycasting, but as you only want it to "fly in the east direction", it should be a lot easier.

You can summon an arrow with no gravity with this command:

```
/summon arrow ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:bomb,NoGravity:1b}
```

Then, to give it the motion, you can run the following command block in a **repeating** (so it doesn't slow down over time) command block:

```
/entitydata @e[type=arrow,name=bomb] {Motion:[0.5,0.0,0.0]}
```

---

If you try this however you might notice that the arrow's movement looks something like this:

[image: Arrow motion]

Minecraft doesn't send information about an entity very often unless it thinks something has significantly changed.

We can "trick" the game into updating the entity more often by constantly alternating a tag such as its `Air`. For example, running constantly each in alternating ticks:

```
/entitydata @e[type=arrow,name=bomb] {Air:2s,Motion:[0.5,0.0,0.0]}
/entitydata @e[type=arrow,name=bomb] {Air:1s,Motion:[0.5,0.0,0.0]}
```

Here's a one-command installer for the commands to alternate between those two commands:

```
summon falling_block ~ ~.6 ~ {Block:chain_command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:fill ~ ~ ~ ~ ~2 ~ air},Time:1,Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:falling_block,Block:activator_rail,Time:1,Passengers:[{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~ ~-3 ~1 command_block 4 replace {Command:summon arrow ~ ~2 ~ {CustomName:bomb,NoGravity:1b},TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-1 ~-3 ~1 air},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~ ~-3 ~2 command_block 4 replace {Command:blockdata ~ ~ ~ {auto:0b},TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-1 ~-3 ~2 chain_command_block 4 replace {Command:blockdata ~1 ~ ~1 {auto:1b},auto:1,TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-2 ~-3 ~2 chain_command_block 4 replace {Command:entitydata @e[type=arrow,name=bomb] {Air:1s,Motion:[0.5,0.0,0.0]},auto:1,TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-3 ~-3 ~2 air},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~ ~-3 ~3 command_block 4 replace {Command:blockdata ~ ~ ~ {auto:0b},TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-1 ~-3 ~3 chain_command_block 4 replace {Command:blockdata ~1 ~ ~-1 {auto:1b},auto:1,TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-2 ~-3 ~3 chain_command_block 4 replace {Command:entitydata @e[type=arrow,name=bomb] {Air:2s,Motion:[0.5,0.0,0.0]},auto:1,TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-3 ~-3 ~3 air},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~ ~-3 ~4 command_block 4 replace {Command:blockdata ~ ~ ~-2 {auto:1b},auto:1,TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-1 ~-3 ~4 command_block 4 replace {Command:fill ~ ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~ air,auto:1,TrackOutput:0b}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~-2 ~-3 ~4 air},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:blockdata ~ ~-3 ~ {Command:,auto:0}},{id:commandblock_minecart,Command:setblock ~ ~-1 ~ command_block 0 1 {auto:1,Command:kill @e[type=commandblock_minecart,r=1]}}]}]}]}
```

(Place down an impulse command block, paste that in, turn it to `Always Active` then press `Done`)

After getting that set up (you will no longer need the repeating block) arrows named `bomb` should move like this:

[image: Smooth arrow motion]

Comment: This is amazing. Is this your own original method or that of another?

Comment: @ExperimentalRocket I've used similar tricks in the past to force an entity to update, but I found out about alternating the `Air` tag specifically (which all entities have, despite it being useless on the ones you'd want to use this trick for) from Onnowhere.